# UIWebview horizontal doesn't work

Tags: ipad, uiwebview

I'm working trying to make one app with xcode very easy, I have already all the app's logic in HTML and I am only trying to put it inside on UIWebview object.

When I have my ipad in vertical, every looks ok no problems but when I put it in horizonal I only can show the half of my screen as you can see in the screenshot.

I use this code:

```
`- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];


    NSURL *myURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://someurl.com"];

    NSURLRequest *myRequest = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:myURL];


    [MyWebView loadRequest:myRequest];

}`
```

[image]

In my file *.storyboard I only join the object with the controller and gave it the dimensions but with my mouse without set anything in the utilities panel,

Thanks a lot!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go to your storyboard:

- Select your `UIWebView` object
- At the bottom you should see the Auto Layout Constraints
- Tap the third button on the left and select Add Missing Constraints

Doing this defaults the `UIWebView` to have a flexible width and height to match its superview.

Comment: Hi! thanks a lot for your answer, I did that but still it continue with the same behavior, I deleted the component and I added it again and still the same. When I add "Add Missing Constraints" that means that it for itself should take all the width and height, right ?